# Drupal 7 Link CCK text field to Node ID

Tags: 7, views

I am creating a view and the Filter Criteria cck text field needs to equal the Node Id. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Include cck text field and node id in your view's field list and then you can make your text field as link to node id.

Also for the filtration you can use contextual filters if required one is not available you can use relations.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the "Contextual Filters" on your view. There you have the possibility to use the current node ID as a filter for the view.

Comment: I've tried that here is what I have: Content:Nid and I tried to make my text field = [node:nid]

Comment: Just figured it out, I was concentrating on NID from contextual filters but that was wrong. I need to make the contextual filter my CCK field then get the ID from the URL.

Comment: Yes, thats how these filters work.